# Bootstrap datepicker unexpectedly fires change event inside another event handler

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I noticed unexpected event firing from Bootstrap datepicker. It only happens inside of another function/handler.

Normally `setDate` shouldn't trigger events and it doesn't! unless I wrap it into another function/handler.

Trying to understand the difference and get rid of unneeded event firing.

Please help.

```
//$('.set-date-button').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var startDate = '01/01/2017';
  $('.start .date').datepicker('setDate', startDate);
//}); When commented, change event doesn't fire, when uncommented - unexpected change event fires.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xek22wpq/

Using `change` or `changeDate` doesn't make any difference.

```js
$('.set-date-button').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var startDate = '01/01/2017';
  $('.start .date').datepicker('setDate', startDate);
});

$(document).on('change', '.start .date', function() {
  alert('fired!');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/master/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/master/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<button class='set-date-button'>Set Date</button>
<div class='start'>
  <input class='date' placeholder='mm/dd/yyyy'>
</div>
```

Comment: Please note that you linked [eonasdan-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) docs, while in your fiddle and your snippet you are using [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). The first component has neither `datepicker` nor `setDate` method. Both fiddle and snippet does not work. Please edit your question specifying what component you are using.

Comment: Wrong link, fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/575

I found that `update` method doesn't trigger `changeDate`, but triggers `change`. And this is how I eliminated this extra firing:

```
$('.set-date-button').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var startDate = '01/01/2017';
  $('.start .date').datepicker('update', startDate);
});

$(document).on('changeDate', '.start .date', function() {
  alert('fired!');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xek22wpq/10/

Answer (score 1):

Because when you create your change event date is already set. If you inverse order it'll fire change event : jsfiddle.net/xek22wpq/9